# Get the battery voltage of Logitech Lightspeed device with IOKit?

Tags: swift, macos, hid, iokit, logitech

I'd like to write a simple tool in Swift to read battery status of my mouse (Logitech G Pro Wireless). Since it's my first dive into both IOKit and managing HID devices, I am struggling with getting it done.

Here's my current approach:

1. I used this library to skip for now messing with Obj-C  https://github.com/Arti3DPlayer/USBDeviceSwift
2. On launch of the app I create HID Device with hardcoded ids and start listening for its presence:

```swift
struct MyApp: App {
   let rfDeviceMonitor = HIDDeviceMonitor([
       HIDMonitorData(vendorId: 0x046d, productId: 0xC539)//0xc088)
       ], reportSize: 64)

   var body: some Scene {
       Window()
           .onAppear {
                  let rfDeviceDaemon = Thread(target: self.rfDeviceMonitor, selector:#selector(self.rfDeviceMonitor.start), object: nil)
                  rfDeviceDaemon.start()
           }
   }

}
```

3. Another class is listening for connection and device's data.

```swift
    func configure() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.usbConnected), name: .HIDDeviceConnected, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.hidReadData), name: .HIDDeviceDataReceived, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func usbConnected(notification: NSNotification) {
        guard let nobj = notification.object as? NSDictionary else {
            return
        }
        
        guard let deviceInfo: HIDDevice = nobj["device"] as? HIDDevice else {
            return
        }
        
        self.deviceInfo = deviceInfo
        write()
    }
    
    @objc func hidReadData(notification: Notification) {
        let obj = notification.object as! NSDictionary
        let data = obj["data"] as! Data
        print([UInt8](data))
    }
    
    func write() {
        let payload: [UInt8] = [
            0x10, // short message
            0xff, // receiver's index
            0x06, // feature index - battery voltage for g pro wireless
            0x00,
            0x00,
            0x00
        ]
        
        var correctData = Data(payload)
        var count = correctData.count
        
        let ret: Int32 = IOHIDDeviceGetReport(
            self.deviceInfo.device,
            kIOHIDReportTypeFeature,
            CFIndex(0x10),
            &correctData,
            &count
        )
        
        print(ret) // 0xe0005000
        print([UInt8](correctData)) // [16, 255, 6, 0, 0, 0]
    }
```

The issue is that IOKit always returns a value (0xe0005000) after calling `IOHIDDeviceGetReport` that is not a success. I have no idea what this means, since kIOReturn header doesn't mention this value at all.

Links that I found useful:

- receiver's properties: https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/blob/78341f87e969fcdb657d912953f919e7bdd7c491/docs/devices/Lightspeed%20Receiver%20C539.txt
- Mouse's properties: https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/blob/78341f87e969fcdb657d912953f919e7bdd7c491/docs/devices/G%20Pro%20Wireless%20Gaming%20Mouse%204079.txt
- feature's and implementation of reading features via hidpp 2.0 https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/blob/eac916b57c78b23a40bcded1a9c89e2cc30e06d4/lib/logitech_receiver/hidpp20.py
- Logitech's specification's draft for hidpp 2.0 https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BxbRzx7vEV7eWmgwazJ3NUFfQ28?resourcekey=0-dQ-Lx1FORQl0KAdOHQaE1A

The most important informations I got from these sites:

- My mouse has only a feature of passing current voltage. It's available on index 6. Also, there's mentioned hex value of `0x1001` next to that feature, but I am not sure what it could mean, maybe it's some Logitech's identifier for this feature.
- buffer size has 7 or 20 bytes (this call should be 7B), where:

  - first means message size (short - 7B - `0x10`, long - 20B - `0x11`)
  - second is device index (`0xFF` is for receiver, yet to find which is meant for device connected via a wire)
  - Third means feature index (which is 6 in this case)
  - Fourth is divided on function and software identifier (in this order). The second one people say that is used to recognize responses meant for us from the rest of the output.
  - rest should be filled by report that I'd like to get.
- https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/blob/d41c60718876957158f2ef7ce51648cab78c72ad/lib/logitech_receiver/base.py#L437 - here's Python's implementation of sending such a request. This line particularly looks like it sends a request, then it waits for a message back? This is the point where I am struggling the most.

There's a line in documentation that describes bytes meaning, says:
"The device index, feature index, function identifier, and software identifier are always returned unchanged.", so I suppose I should use `getReport` instead of `setReport`, but again, my knowledge is very limited here, so I tried `setReport` as well, but with no luck. Same error has been thrown.

Comment: In IOUSBHostFamilyDefinitions.h, `kUSBHostReturnPipeStalled` is defined to represent the value `0xe0005000`. To recover from this you'll need to call `ClearPipeStall`/`ClearPipeStallBothEnds` on the pipe. However, the fact you got into this situation in the first place usually suggests you sent a request to the device that it didn't understand, e.g. wrong length, etc. (I'm not familiar with Arti3DPlayer though.)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by filling the report buffer with data before requesting the report from the device? To the best of my knowledge, `IOHIDDeviceGetReport` only *writes* to the buffer. So if you're trying to send those bytes to the device, you'll need to do so another way. (e.g. `IOHIDDeviceSetReport`?)

Comment: Note that I'm not familiar with the feature reports you're trying to use here and I'm also not going to wade through 40 specification documents to answer a question on here (and I expect neither will most people who might be able to help), so you might want to update your post to quote the relevant part of the specification you're trying to implement if it's unclear to you how to turn it into specific IOKit calls.

Comment: Ad.3 You're right, I updated post with the most important informations and pieces of code, that I stuck with, thank You.

Ad. 1 I've tried different sizes (6, which is present in the post's code, 7 and 8), yet  error didn't disappear. I am 100% sure that the device id is valid, since it doesn't breakpoint when device is unplugged.

Ad 2. Way I understood documentation is that I have to send report with prefilled data about its identifier (device id, feature id, and so on), then get rest of the data via getReport, where device fills rest of the buffer (see end of the post update)

Comment: I've had a quick browse through the Python example, and nowhere does it appear to work with HID reports. Instead, [it looks like it's using raw USB device (control?) requests.](https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/blob/eac916b57c78b23a40bcded1a9c89e2cc30e06d4/lib/logitech_receiver/hidpp20.py#L1115) Here too, USB has no concept of "filling out the rest of the buffer." There are no read-write requests. You can either send data to the device, or you can receive data from the device. (My familiarity with Python is limited, so it's not clear to me what `*params` is, which would probably help.)

Comment: For identifying the kind of data you are trying to read when making an *input* control request (get data from device), [you provide the request type, 'index’, and 'value'](https://beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb6.shtml). If you need to send a buffer with data *to* the device first, that needs to be a separate *output* request.

Comment: It sounds like there's documentation for this protocol. My personal approach would be to read the docs and to make sure I understand the exact way these feature requests work and how that maps to HID reports and USB requests before attempting to throw API calls against the wall to see what sticks.